# Half day in jQuery ui Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am currently using the jQuery UI Datepicker script in order to display availability dates for a rental. I used the recommended way to feed the script am an array of disabled days but my problem is that the day rental ends should also be available as a start date for a new rental. The client asked for a red triangle on the first and last day to show it should be available. How can I achieve that with this plugin?

```
$(function() {
    <?php

    $date_range = array();
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE cid='$chalet[id]' and status='1'");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
        $date_range1 = createDateRangeArray(date("Y-m-d", $r[arrive]), date("Y-m-d", $r[depart]));

        // How can i use those 2 arrays to detect the right triangle to display and make sure the day is selectable
        $first[] = reset($date_range1);
        $last[] = end($date_range1);

        $date_range = array_merge($date_range, $date_range1);
    }

    foreach ($date_range as $key => $values) {
        $dates .= '"' . $values . '", ';
    }
    if ($dates) {
        echo 'var disableddates = [' . substr($dates, 0, -2) . "];\n";
    } else {
        echo "var disableddates = [];\n";
    }

    ?>
    function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
    $( "#calendrier" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
    });
});
```

The above code renders the following

[image]:

I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope u'll get the idea, pardon if there are any errors as its written straight from brain without any testing. This adds .arrival / .departure classes to given day.

PHP:

```
$arrivals = $departures = $disabledDates = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $arrivals[] = $r['arrive'];
    $departures[] = $r['departure'];
    $disabledDates[] = ....
```

JS

```
var arrivals = <?=json_encode($arrivals)?>;
var departures = <?=json_encode($departures)?>;
var disabledDates = <?=json_encode($disabledDates)?>;


$( "#calendrier" ).datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var myDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('YYYY-mm-dd', date);

        if($.inArray(myDate, disabledDates)) 
            return [false];
        else if($.inArray(myDate, arrivals)) 
            return [true, 'arrival', 'Arrival day'];
        else if($.inArray(myDate, departures)) 
            return [true, 'departure', 'Departure day'];
        else
            return [true];
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a great start thx man. just tried your script corrected the JS bugs and tested it out and every day of every month is blocked now hehe will try to work it out but if you see the bug let me know.

Comment: glad I could help ;)

Comment: @WebiumMedia Could you post what you got working as an answer?